# How can I create my own JAR file for an Android application using Eclipse or Ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant, android

How can I create my own JAR file for an Android application using Eclipse or Ant?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can use the "export" option on the project to create a jar file. This will open the JAR creation wizard.

Tip: While creating the jar, choose to save the jar description file in your project workspace. Then subsequently, just right click the jar description file and select "`create jar`" to recreate the jar file whenever you need.